# refreshControl with programatic UITableView without UITableViewController

Tags: swift, refresh, tableview

I created my UITableView instance programmatically, and added it to the root view as a sub view. I also set the delegate and dataSource for the table view instance programatically. So this table view does not have a table view controller. Now I want to make the table view be able to pull down to refresh. I learned some code from Google, like so:

```
var refresh = UIRefreshControl();
refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh");
refresh.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged);
self.refreshControl = refresh;
```

Now, the question is the `self` refers to the table view controller. However, in this context, I don't have a table view controller. So do I have to create a table view controller just in order to implement the pull down to refresh function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

//1: Add an instance variable to your ViewController.

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

//2: In viewDidLoad() set up your refresh control

```
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

//3: And (still in the viewDidLoad()) add it as a subview to the tableView (UITableView)

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

//4: Finally, in your refresh() function: do not forget to end the refreshing of this control.

```
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

// Be aware, this (*end of refreshing*) must be done on the main queue! - if you are not there. In such case you might use something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
 }
```

Remarks to your code:

1. You do not have to use semicolons anymore :-).
2. Refresh control and the refresh control selector can not have the same name (i.e. *action: "refresh"*).
3. There is no "self.refreshControl = refresh;".